# Get File Names in Web Directory with Swift

Tags: http, swift2, nsurlsession

I've got an archive located at my web site with files in it that I'd like users of my app to be able to access.  Files at this location may be changing so I'd like to be able download a file list that is then presented to the users, who would then click on the file(s) to download.

I think I've got the downloading handled with NSURLSession, but I can't find a direct way to get a list of the files located at http://www.example.com/archive/ in Swift.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  By the way, I'm not well versed in most aspects of "web programming" so small words would be appreciated if this involves stuff like POST and GET. Thanks.

Comment: First You should check if your web server has Directory Browsing capability enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I gave up trying to solve this directly.  Since it's my website, I ended up creating a simple php file to list the directory items and then get that output via Swift.